# Javascript and jQuery problem using .append() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails-plugin

I'm having trouble in appending a div with the .append function from jQuery in a Grails .gsp. The problem is that the div I'm trying to append is a RichUI star rating block which is programmatically written when I use the  tag. The code is the following:

**Code in Grails .gsp:**

```
var textToInsert = [];
textToInsert[1] = '<tr><td>';
textToInsert[2] = artistData.name;
textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div id="artist2"><richui:rating dynamic="true" id="2" units="5" rating="0"  controller="rating" action="rate"/></div></td></tr>';

$j('#recommendedList').append(textToInsert.join(''));
```

**And the html produced is precisely this:**

```
var textToInsert = [];
                textToInsert[1] = '<tr><td>';
                textToInsert[2] = artistData.name;
                textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id='r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82'>
<div class='ratingblock'>  
 <div id='unit_longr3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82'>
  <ul id='unit_ulr3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82' class='unit-rating' style='width: 150px'>
    <li id='r9cd7abbd875dc72e67c84180c5b41704' class='current-rating' style='width: 0px;'>Currently 0.0</li>
    <li><a href="/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2?rating=1" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82','/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'rating=1'});return false;" class="r1-unit rater" title="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2?rating=2" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82','/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'rating=2'});return false;" class="r2-unit rater" title="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2?rating=3" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82','/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'rating=3'});return false;" class="r3-unit rater" title="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2?rating=4" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82','/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'rating=4'});return false;" class="r4-unit rater" title="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2?rating=5" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82','/Ontourtest/rating/rate/2',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,parameters:'rating=5'});return false;" class="r5-unit rater" title="5">5</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div></td></tr>';

$j('#recommendedList').append(textToInsert.join(''));
```

Firebug gives the error: missing ; before statement `textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div ...='r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82'>`

My guess is that as the richui tag writes new line characters without semi colons, it produces javascript errors, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?
Thanks very much!

Comment: it seems your issue that the dynamic markup is using a single quote instead of a double quote. the string is prematurely ended. `'</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id='r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82'>
<div class='ratingblock'>` should read `'</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id="r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82">
<div class="ratingblock">` paying attention specifically to the id and class identifiers.

Comment: @f0x: That is correct, so the code in the rating component would have to be changed so that it could be used in a string.

Answer (score 0):

What this means it that there is an error on this line (and all following lines, i'm not copying them all):

```
textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id='r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82'>
```

and i think that the error is that you are not escaping single quotes. You could use double quotes:

```
textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id="r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82">'
```

If you want to keep single quotes you need to escape them:

```
textToInsert[3] = '</td><td><div id="artist2"><div id=\'r3a44146338e7d18384c9233cb7f7bb82\'>
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that those lines are produced by the RichUI plug in. I don't know how to modify them, or if it is even possible.